# Heroku with jenkins -heroku is not recognized as an internal or external command in jenkins and Email not received

Tags: heroku, jenkins, deployment, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following pipeline script which i have written assuming if the commands on cmd would work it should do the same on the pipeline script (which is wrong)

```
node{
    stage "CI"
    git 'https://github.com/NaveenDK/mentalshortcuts.git'
    bat "npm install"  
}
    def notify(status){
    emailext (
      to: "ddd@dd.com",
      subject: "${status}: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'",
      body: """<p>${status}: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
        <p>Check console output at <a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a></p>""",
    )
}

node {
    notify("Deploy to staging?")
}

input 'Deploy to Staging?'

node {
    stage "deploy to staging"
    bat  "heroku git:remote -a blooming-tor-31315"
    bat "git push heroku master"
}
```

Even though deployment works fine in the command prompt when I use the above script and build the jenkins job what I get in the console output is "heroku is not recognized as ...."

And I wont receive the email even though the console says 'sending email to:..."
I have filled the Extended Email notification section in the configuration settings
as follows:
SMTP: smtp.gmail.com
SSL checked and port is 465
So Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You have made a bad assumption that if you can run a command in a shell, then Jenkins will be able to. You have to be running it as the exact same ID as jenkins is using, and using the exact same environment setup. In linux, in particular, different files get sourced depending on whether you are in an interactive logon or a program executing.

Use the bat commands in your build to research what is going on. Look at the PATH, find the commands, etc.

Comment: Thanks .After several hours of research I found out it’s better to let heroku decide whether it should deploy or not by checking “auto deployment if Ci is successful “ I’m guessing that the GitHub repo itself has a way of saying heroku that “ok now that my Jenkins build is successful you can go ahead and deploy”  but , still I haven’t found the complete answer to this problem .. I will update once found . Thanks Rob Hales